# Find isomorphism of graph with maximal number $x$ such that $f(x)\neq x$ - assuming $NP=P$

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity, np, graph-isomorphism

> For $f : V → V$ which is authomorphism of directed graph $G = (V, E)$,
>   $$\#f = |\{v : f(v) \neq v\}|$$  For graph $G$ we denote:   $$\#G =
>  \max\{\#f : \text{$f$ is isomorphism $G$} \}$$
>
> Prove that if $P = NP$ then function $G\to\#G$ is polynomially
>   computable.

My problem is that I can't think about isomorphisms. I know that thanks to assumption in polynomial time I can check if two graphs are isomorphic. The problem is however that I can't generate candidate for checking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the decision version of computing $\#G$:

$L=\{(G,k) | \text{$G$ has an automorphism $f$ with $\#f\ge k$}\}$

$L$ is obviously in NP (an automorphism $f$ with $\#f\ge k$ is a witness). If $\mathsf{P=NP}$ then $L\in P$, and you can compute $\#G$ in polynomial time using binary search.

Comment: can it be $L=\{(G,k) | \text{$G$ has an automorphism $f$ with $\#f = k$}\}$ in place of your $L=\{(G,k) | \text{$G$ has an automorphism $f$ with $\#f\ge k$}\}$. And binary search is also not needed

Comment: You can define $L$ that way, but you will still need to search for the maximum in order to compute $\#G$ (one oracle call to $L$ is not enough).